# Import python modules

Tags: import

I am running Blender 2.49 with Python27 (for testing) and am trying to import webbrowser and os. When I try webbrowser the console returns "no module named webbrowser" when I try os it returns "no module named genericpath". This is extremely annoying as I've looked at various forums on how to do things such as adding the module to Blenders script path and what not, but nothing has worked. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: why are you using 2.49? UNless you have a good reason to use 2.49 you should be using 2.7. There is a huge difference between the two.

Comment: As for testing, I don't think you will find more than ten people that still have 2.49 installed and none of them would use it very often. Python scripting in 2.49 and 2.6x is not compatible so you don't need to test any new scripts in 2.49. I would say 2.63 being the first version with bmesh would be the **extreme** oldest version to test any scripts with and depending on what your script does you may have trouble getting it to work an a version that old.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answers and i understand why using new versions is important. The problem is that I want to make 3d printing calculator with php. But to get the dimensions of the objects im passing them through blender and running a script that is out dated and doesn't work with newer versions of blender.

Comment: There are a lot of useful tools in recent Blender versions to measure and prepare for 3d printing: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/Print_Tools

Comment: Wow that looks great! Thanks for the link, I'll see if I can just incorporate those tools with the new version then.